# Angular - Error PromiseReactionJob in IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, typescript, mobile

My website (built in Angular) doesn't work on IOS, when it opens only a blank page appears and the browser returns the PromiseReactionJob error (in any browser), but only on mobile (tablets, iphone...), I've tried it on mac and it works perfectly . After researching a little bit about the error it still doesn't work. Does anyone know how to solve?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the exact error was in this question: I had a very similar problem, where an Ipad was showing a blank page, and the only evidence that it had tried to do anything was a PromiseReactionJob error.

The root cause was that I was targeting `es2020` in my Javascript compilation, and the device involved was running Safari 13. It didn't recognize something in the Javascript, and when it tried to bootstrap, it encountered an error. (The issue was slightly harder to troubleshoot because any errors caught from `platformBrowserDynamic` were sent to the console with `console.error`, not `console.trace`. I didn't have a root cause until I changed that.)

The solution was to update the device to iOS 15. Safari 15 came along for the ride, and was able to handle my code.

Comment: You saved my life!

For posterity, I'm using Vite, and the HMR server would give this error while testing with Browserstack (if I compiled the code and served it on a simple server it works. Just Vite's HMR broke it somehow). I read this post and realized that I was sort of arbitrarily picking an older iPhone. When I tested it with the latest iPhone (and Safari) it worked!!!